# Standardized differences between means in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, standard-error

There is data on a sample of 1,216 students that I'm missing, but I know the means and standard deviation of some key demographics on them. I have a subsample (120 students) with the means and standard deviations.

Since these are not independent samples, is there a way for me to calculate the standard differences in R Studio without having the raw data on all 1,216 students?

For example, lets say the average age and standard deviation in the big group is 14.4 (.5), whereas in my subsample it is 12.9 (.44).

I know I can do t-tests using the library(BSDA) tsum.test command without having raw data:

tsum.test(mean.x=14.4, s.x=.5, n.x=1216, 
          mean.y=12.9, s.y=.44, n.y=120)

But is there a way to do standardized differences without having the raw data? Is there any alternative way to test this, given my missing information?

Comment: No. Your missing the majority of your data. You do not know the distribution of this data.

Comment: At first, the t-test is invalid, as you said the two samples are not independent.

Comment: I'm not proposing to use the t-test for my purposes here. I used it only as an example of code that can be run when you have mean, standard deviation, and sample size, but not the underlying data.

Comment: Think hard why t test is invalid. Then you will find that difference in meaningless.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you can explain this to me, please leave a reply below. I'm not asking as part of a game, this is my job and a serious question as I'm struggling to make use of data I have.

Comment: Total number of students in the sample is 1216. If the sub-sample size is 120, 500, 1000, 1215, what will happen?